# elasticsearch copy field when indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I would like to create a one to many relashanship for the purpose of aggregations.
The "join" will be according to a field called "common_id":

- When I create the first document belonging to the same group I would like to use it's flakeId (it's _id) as the common_id.
- When adding other document belonging to the same group I would like to explicitly set the common_id to have the same value as the first document I added. This can be done by my app since my application will know the common_id of the first element.

My problem is with the first document:
How can i tell elasticsearch to copy the _id into common_id in a single call to elastic (I know I can do it using update script, or using two calls one for index and one for update... but this requires two requests instead of one).

I would like a simple syntax for this.

thanks

Comment: You can insert document into ElasticSearch determine its Id when inserting.

Comment: thanks but this is not good since i want to use elastic flakeIds

Comment: How do you determine that a set of documents belong to the same group?

Comment: the application determines

Comment: @Eli i ended up working with UUID instead as u suggested. Its even shorter than the flakeId

Comment: @OferEliassaf if the application determines it why can't it provide a `groupID` which you then insert and aggregate by?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev - i wanted to use flakeId so i won't need to handle id management in the application side. Like i answered to Eli - i will use UUID for this and that's it.